# depth of Binary Search Tree recursively

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree, depth

**THIS IS HOMEWORK, DO NOT POST CODE. Please and thank you.**

I have been assigned to create a method that calculates the depth of a particular in a BST.

To do this, I am to `@Override` a method `public int depth(T data)`. So, to find it recursively, I need to create a helper method.

I know that I need to essentially search the tree for the node with the data I'm looking for. So, to do this, I've written the following code:

```
@Override
public int depth(T data) {
    if (data == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data is null");
    }
    if (compare(data, root.getData()) == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return countNodes(search(root, data), data);
    }
}

private int countNodes(BSTNode<T> node, T data) {
    int depth = 1;
    if (node == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (compare(data, node.getData()) == 0) {
            return depth;
        } else if (compare(data, node.getData()) < 0) {
            return countNodes(node.getLeft(), data);
        } else {
            return countNodes(node.getRight(), data);
        }
    }
}

private int compare(T a, T b) {
    return a.compareTo(b);
}
```

However, this isn't going to work, as `depth` would remain `1` each time the recursive call is made; essentially, it's resetting the value of depth. I have no idea how to keep the value of `depth` in-between calls.

Comment: Pass int depth as a Reference Integer variable to countNodes and increment it inside the node == null else section at the top.

Comment: You want depth of each node or maximum depth of tree!!!

Comment: Given a node, I need to run down the tree to that node. The depth should be the number of ancestor nodes it has.

@shazin I tried that--but reference integers have to be of type Object, don't that? I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your depth method should return one if the current node is the one you are looking for or the depth of the next node down plus one if you need to keep looking.

For example:

```
                        N5
                    N3      N7
                  N1  N4  N6
```

You want to know the depth of N1.

You start at the root:

N1 != N5 so you return one plus the result of your check on N3. (1 + (result of N3 check))

N1 != N3 so you return one plus the result of your check on N1. (1 + (1 + (result of N1 check)))

N1 == N1 so you you return one. (1 + (1 + (1)))

(1 + (1 + (1))) = 3

this is the correct depth and is what the initial depth call will return.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The root (head) of the BST has depth of 1. The next element down (either left or right) has depth 2, and so on. Depth is the number of ancestor nodes a given node has.